# Trouble getting model validations to work correctly for a related model pair

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to implement a voting feature similar to that of Reddit's, for both a parent and a child model (Links and comments, but my case, for Question, which `has_many` answers).

The vote feature currently works fine for when voting for questions, but when it comes to answers, users could only vote for **one** answer that appears for a given question, but not for any subsequent ones (unlike SO, which lets you vote for as many answers as you'd like..)

I identified my issue to be in my `Vote.rb` file (when its commented out, it works..), which appears as the following:

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :question_id, :answer_id, :up # up is a boolean used for voting

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :answer 

  validates :user_id, :uniqueness => { :scope => :question_id } #this line causes the issue..

end
```

The validation works for questions by guaranteeing that a user could only vote for a question once, but since I am rendering the answers in a Question's `show` page, my hunch is that `user_id`/`question_id` uniqueness rule is hindering it from working for answer_ids as well.  If possible, I was wondering if I could structure the validation so it validates `answer_id`/`user_id` uniqueness first, and then the question/user pair.. although I don't know if that logic is correct and will get it to work.

Thanks for your help!

---

As supplementary material, here is my controller:

```
class VotesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @vote = Vote.where(params[:vote].slice(:question_id, :answer_id).merge(:user_id => current_user.id)).first
    if @vote
      @vote.up = params[:vote][:up]
      @vote.save
    else
      @vote = current_user.votes.create(params[:vote])
    end
    redirect_to :back
  end
end
```

Comment: What does your question and answer models look like?

Comment: Validations can have arbitrary conditions using the `:if` or `:unless` option. But I don't think you can do it with just combinations of uniqueness validations. Unless you duplicated data, I think you need to make a custom validation to validate that a user only votes on one answer per question.

Comment: Thanks - a different set of validations was what I ended up using.  Also, someone else pointed out that polymorphous associations may have been the best for my `Vote` model, since both comments and questions utilize vote, but to different means.